# gmail api messages.list returns messages that do not show up in the UI

Tags: gmail-api

When I retrieve messages via

```
"gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=\"#{query}\"&maxResults=1&access_token=#{access_token}"
```

I get 1 message, but when I run the same query in the gmail UI, I do (correctly) not find it

```
in:Inbox after:1969-12-30 -in:MyLabel
```

but the message clearly has MyLabel ... so I'll have to download all messages and then manually do the label checking ... which is pretty shitty ... any explanation why this might be happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok ... derp ... properly encoding the query helps ... q=#{CGI.escape(query)} worked ...